# HTML DIV Padding Wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html

Why my div is not padding correct ?

```
    <div class="padding_10">
      <input placeholder="Search for people..." style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
    .padding_10 { padding: 10px; }
```

[image]

Comment: share the css properties of `padding_10`

Comment: check whether other css property is not override the your `.padding_10` property.

Comment: It is working as expected. You want to add padding to the input?

Comment: are you write your css property in style tag or css file ?

Comment: Looks like div has got padding. Also check there are no other css rules over riding the padding on this div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input border default addedd

you apply width 100% in your input

apply width in `calc` function

```
<div class="padding_10">
      <input placeholder="Search for people..." style="width:calc(100% - 2px); border:1px solid #000;">
    </div>
```

Comment: Why calc - border when box-sizing: border-box; exists?

Answer (score 0):

**First** just to be sure is your `css` is inside `style` `tag` like

```
<style>
.padding_10{ padding: 10px; }
</style>
```

**Second** if your is inside `style tag` then just `right click`(use firebug) on tag and inspect  all `styles` for that div. May be some other styles are there so `padding` not working